# Attempting to download a Gradle Plugin results in an error

Tags: gradle

I've been trying to work on this for hours now, but I'm not sure what the problem is specifically.  If it helps, I'm doing this in Visual Studio.

```
Plugin [id: 'fabric-loom', version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT/'] was not found in any of the following sources:
- Gradle Core Plugins (not a core plugin, please see https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/standard_plugins.html for available core plugins)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'fabric-loom:fabric-loom.gradle.plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT/')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Fabric(https://maven.fabricmc.net/)
    MavenRepo
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your IDE and everything to do with your build tool (Gradle).  The fact that you're using a snapshot build is suspect given that version 1.0.3 looks like it's available.

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.fabricmc/fabric-loom, https://maven.fabricmc.net/fabric-loom/fabric-loom.gradle.plugin/ Repo lookup issue?